# Unrecognized selector sent to instance UITableView cell push to TabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm just trying send the mid to customerDetailviewcontroller and segue is going tabbar controller first.

There is my prepareforsegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ApiClass *apiClass = [self.customerCards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CustomerDetailViewController *customerDetailViewController = (CustomerDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        customerDetailViewController.mid = apiClass.mid;



    }
}
```

_mid    NSString *  @"1642"

That is the error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setMid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x126e53580'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1838d6530 0x1948ac0e4 0x1838dd5f4 0x1838da3ac 0x1837dec4c 0x1000ae2b4 0x1886b401c 0x18820ce14 0x1882ca6dc 0x188166b8c 0x1880d85f0 0x18388ed98 0x18388bd24 0x18388c104 0x1837b91f4 0x18cbdb6fc 0x18814a10c 0x1000e2b08 0x194f2aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

There is the data I'm getting from json.So it is not nil.

http://prntscr.com/6lzjkd

Comment: Could you add which selector is not found? Don't be afraid to add code or error messages, just be sure to add them in code blocks (start with 4 spaces).

Comment: I am editing the question now

Comment: And `CustomerDetailViewController` is of what type?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out this.Main Problem I push the segue to tabbar controller.And I fixed it with this code.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ApiClass *apiClass = [self.customerCards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [segue destinationViewController];
    CustomerDetailViewController *customerDetailViewController = (CustomerDetailViewController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
    customerDetailViewController.mid = apiClass.mid;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to execute the method `setMid:`, but it can't find that one. Did you set the property `mid` as `readwrite`?

Comment: I set property like this.

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *mid;

Comment: Then it should work. Try using `customerDetailViewController.setMid(apiClass.mid)`. Did you put the declaration in the `.h` file?

Comment: which `.h` file tableviewController or `destinationviewcontroller`

Comment: @MuratKaya `CustomerDetailViewController`

Comment: have you tried setting the segue identifier as "showDetail"